# Have I done this correctly? (Interface and Class code to compile successfully)

Tags: java, class, interface

**Given:** Consider  the  following  interface  and  class: What must  be  true  about  the  code  for  class  C  in  order  for that code to compile successfully?

```java
    public interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
    }


    public class C implements I {
      // code for class C
    }
```

This is my (PREVIOUS) answer:

```
    public interface I {
    public void m1();

    default public void m2 {
        System.out.println("default m2");
      }
    }

    public class C implements I {
       public void m1()
      }
    C c = new C();          
    c.m2();
```

Any way to improve this? Did I change the original code too much? It's my homework but I need feedback. I'm new to Interfaces. Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT :** I've tried doing this

```
    interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
}

public class C implements I {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        public void m1() {
            System.out.println("To be honest..");
        }
        public void m2() {
            System.out.println("It's a vague question to begin with.");
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    C why = new C();  
    why.m1();
    why.m2();
    }
}
```

*Output:*

> error: illegal start of expression **public void m1() {**

I don't know why this error shows up I simply did what this website has done: [source](https://www.w3schools.com/java/tryjava.asp?filename=demo_interface) but my compiler kept on insisting on making me insert a `public static void main(String[] args){` even though I already had one at the bottom. The only error I'm getting is the `illegal start of expression` on the `public void m1(){`

Comment: Well I'm not sure what `C c = new C(); c.m2();` is doing there? Also your indentation is non existent and the `m1` method has a typo.

Comment: However surely just testing this yourself would give you a better idea of whether it compiles?

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html

Answer (score 2):

> "Did I change the original code too much?"

IMO, yes.  The question asks "What must be true about the code for class C in order for that code to compile successfully?".  That is asking how you should change `C` to make it compile.  It doesn't mention changing `I`.

This would be a better answer:

```
public class C implements I {
    public void m1() {
         // do something
    }

    public void m2() {
         // do something else
    }
}
```

The non-code (i.e. English) answer is that `C` needs to implement the `m1` and `m2` methods declared by `I` ... with the same signatures and compatible return types and `throws` clauses.

There are a couple of additional caveat.  The `I` and `C` code needs to be in separate files (since both are top-level types and `public`).  That means that they each should have a `package` statement at the start.

---

FWIW, there is another answer:

```
public class C {}
```

Remove the `implements I` and `C` will compile.  But I don't think that this is the answer that the person asking the question *expects*.

Answer (score 0):

I think the objective is to change class C only and not the interface.
Not doing your work assignment, only code where it says:
// code for class C

Answer (score 0):

When a interface is implemented by a Class, **we need to provide the implementation for the methods declared in interface in the implemented Class.**

Interfaces provides just declaration of the methods and the definition of those methods should be given in the implemented Class.

We can use default keyword for a method in Interface to provide an implemented instead of declaration ( available from Java 8). In such cases, method whose definition is not provided should be implemented in the class C

As per the question -- code should be given inside Class C.
So, changing the interface method won't be the perfect answer.

```
public class C implements I {
        public void m1(){
            System.out.println("simply a method definition");
        }
        public void m2(){
            System.out.println("simply a method definition");
        }


        }
```

Comment: Note that you're not overriding anything... you're implementing the methods of the interface. Also, I'd recommend against adding `;` at the end of method bodies like this. It doesn't cause an error, but it's confusing.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't see a problem with that phrasing. [Java 8 Trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) calls this *overriding of the supertype methods*.

Comment: @JonSkeet Providing implementation for a method of a interface can be called as overriding. though rephrased for a even better understanding

Comment: @StephenFrancis: I would strongly advise against using that terminology unless the interface provides a default implementation. The word "overriding" gives the impression of providing a new implementation that is used instead of another one... whereas that's not the case here.

Comment: @JanezKuhar: See my response to Stephen. I think that in the absence of a default implementation, it's confusing and not in tune with the normal meaning of the term.

Answer (score 0):

An ideal way to make your code compile without much changes would be to override methods of interface in class. Also, if interface and class are defined in single file, remove access modifier of interface.

Solution -

```
interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
}
public class C implements I {
    // code for class C
    @Override
    public void m1() {}

    @Override
    public void m2() {}
}
```

Alternatively, if you would like to define a default method in interface, you would do so as follows -

```
interface I {
    public void m1();
    default public void m2() {
        System.out.println("default m2");
    }
}
public class C implements I {
    public void m1() {
        C c = new C();
        c.m2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One word can do the job.

But first:

> ```
> C c = new C();          
> c.m2();
> ```

I have no idea why you added that or what it is trying to accomplish. I assume it's left-over test code you accidentally pasted in. But if it's not, this makes no sense - just get rid of it / explain what this is trying to do.

The essence of the problem is that a class that implements an interface must have an implementation for every method mentioned in the interface. There are many ways to solve this problem:

- Remove the methods from the interface (just delete the 2 lines declaring methods in `I` - voila!
- Give the methods default implementations in the interface, which removes the need for classes that implement the interface to provide implementations of these methods - you've more or less done that. This is probably the most complicated way to solve the problem, though!
- Give the class implementations for the stated method.
- Just make the class abstract - abstract classes do not have to provide implementations for all of the methods it inherited that ordinarily would.

That last one is your 'simplest' answer. It's a one-word change:

```
public interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
}

public abstract class C implements I {}
```

However, this belies a more core issue with this question:

**It's a stupid question!**

The question explicitly states: "What MUST be true about the code for class C" - and as I showed above, there is no one answer to this question.

If we make some assumptions about the lack of rigor on the part of the one asking the question, I'd guess that the intent is to presume that `abstract` doesn't exist as a concept, and that the interface as provided is to be taken as is and cannot be changed. In which case, the only correct answer is that the C class needs to have implementations for both methods. Thus, whilst there are many answers and making C abstract is the simplest, if I look into my crystal ball and make a few assumptions about what the question author is (badly) attempting to accomplish here, they're looking for this:

```
public interface I {
    public void m1();
    public void m2();
}

public class C implements I {
    @Override public void m1() {}
    @Override public void m2() {}
}
```

Whilst not neccessary, you should always also stick an `@Override` annotation on those methods, so, `@Override public void m1() {}`. This is compiler-checked documentation: If you stick that annotation on a method that isn't actually overriding anything (for example, because you made a typo), the compiler will tell you about it, which is great. You *can* leave them off if you want (`m1() {}` will be overriding whether that annotation is there or not - the annotation simply ensures that if it isn't overriding anything, the compiler will error out).